# Android Imagebutton with gradient background

Tags: android

For days I tried to implement a simple Imagebutton in Android, using a dynamic LinearGradient as background. I want the base design from android.R.drawable.btn_default, which is colored starting from the left edge of the button to a value given in percent from v = 0-100%(right edge). The edge between the left and right part of the button should be sharp (like an equalizer). For any suggestions without NullException errors I would be very thankful!

**EDIT 29.07.14**

Here is the code snippet, working without errors:

```
 Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
 dr.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
 dr.draw(canvas);

 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
 paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()*7*vol, 0, new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.TRANSPARENT }, new float[] { 0, 1 }, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
 canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

 mButtonSpeech.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
```

But even without the middle part of my code, adding the gradient to the canvas, the button background does not look like I expect it (it is to small and in the center not colored like the other buttons, where I set the backgrund by:

```
 mButtonDraw.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

If I also draw the Paint into Canvas, I would expect the default button background, colored in the left part, like I could do it with setColorFilter().

Comment: If you want to design the base design of the Android default button, I would recommend looking inside the SDK to find the original 9-patch PNG of `R.drawable.btn_default` and modify using an image editor (Photoshop, Gimp, etc.).

Comment: Why don't you simply use that android drawable as your background, then?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I already found the PNGs in the SDK Folder. Is it possible to scale it according to the volume v between 0 and 100%, that the amount of green in the left half can be changed programmatically?

Comment: I already tried to use that android drawable, but the result doesn't look like the expected. (See my edit)